# How to convert GeomSHP to WKB

Tags: python, point, spatial-database, shapefile

I have imported a point shapefile called site_locations.shp into a personal geodatabase. Now I'm trying to retrieve the data from the database using SQL:

```
dbpath = os.path.normpath(r'../geodata/site_locations.mdb') #<br>
msacon = pypyodbc.win_connect_mdb(dbpath) #<br>
msacur = msacon.cursor() #<br>
sqlstr = "SELECT ID, Shape, Notes FROM site_locations" #<br>
msacur.execute(sqlstr) #<br>
rows = msacur.fetchall() #<br>
```

I did the same with a sqlite database and I got the geometry in the so-called well known binary format (WKB). I was able to convert that WKB to well known text (WKT) and then to objects with x and y values. Apparently the field Shape does not contain data in WKB format, but in GeomSHP format. Is there a way in Python to convert this GeomSHP to WKB or so? I understand that some spatial databases have a function called CGeomWKB. Is there a Python implementation?

Comment: If you are working with ArcGIS 10.l you can use SearchCursor.da to retrieve a features shape in WKB. Just use the 'SHAPE@WKB' token. See [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had a look at shapefile.py and was able to arrive at this solution:

```
from struct import unpack
points = []
msacur.execute("SELECT ID, Shape FROM site_locations")

# Field Shape contains binary data in GeomSHP format - to be converted
rows = msacur.fetchall()
```

```
for row in rows:
    # Find out the shape type
    shapeType = unpack("<i", row[1][0:4])[0] 
    if not shapeType in (1, 11, 21):
        print "Found shape is not a point - ignored ..."
    else:
        # Possible shape types are POINT, POINTZ and POINTM - 1, 11 and 21 resp.
        point = unpack("<2d", row[1][4:20])
        x = point[0]
        y = point[1]
        points.append({"id":int(row[0]), "lat":y, "lon":x})
        # TODO: parse remaining 8 or 16 bytes in case of POINTZ / POINTM
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use GDAL/OGR to [execute SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) on either the shapefile, or the [ESRI Personal GeoDatabase (PGeo)](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html).

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions()
ds = ogr.Open(path_to_data_source)
lyr = ds.ExecuteSQL('SELECT ID, Notes FROM site_locations')
for idx in range(lyr.GetFeatureCount()):
    feat = lyr.GetFeature(idx)
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    wkb = geom.ExportToWkb()  # here it is
    feat = geom = None
ds = lyr = None  # close dataset
```

There are also other export formats, such as WKT, GML, KML and GeoJSON.

Comment: Any solution in pure Python?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of, but you might be able to find some way to map the data structures from [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) (which reads shapefiles) to [geomet](https://github.com/geomet/geomet) (which writes WKB). Both of these are pure Python libraries.